# An increasing counter for occurence of new values in R

Tags: r, counter

I am trying to make a counter which increases for each new change in another vector. E.g. I have several individuals that are observed over several weeks, and I want to know how many weeks they are observed. So I'll end up with a table like this:

```
     Id   year Week  Weeks observed
      1   2006   10       1
      1   2006   10       1
      1   2006   11       2
      1   2006   11       2
      1   2006   12       3
      1   2006   13       4
      1   2007    1       5
      1   2007    2       6
      1   2007    3       7
      1   2007    4       8
      1   2007    5       9
      1   2007    6      10
      2   2006   10       1
      2   2006   10       1
      2   2006   11       2
      2   2006   11       2
      2   2006   12       3
      2   2006   13       4
      2   2007    1       5
      2   2007    2       6
      2   2007    3       7
      2   2007    4       8
      2   2007    5       9
      2   2007    6      10
```

Comment: Why does the count not change at the end of the second Id?

Comment: Should the `counter` for Id 2 be `1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4`?

Comment: You need to think carefully when updating your question. For example, you question mentions `tapply` - but that is really referring to my answer. Give a simple example of what you want to do.

Comment: Tried to make better example now, pardon the mess.

Comment: Unfortunately, your edits have changed the question drastically enough that the two originally posted answers are no longer sufficient. It is an interesting question, though.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have your data in a data.frame called `dat`, you could use `tapply` and convert `Phase` to a factor then strip it of its levels to use the underlying integer values:

```
dat$newcounter <- unlist(tapply(dat$Phase, dat$Id,
  function(x) unclass(as.factor(x))))
```

Obligatory `data.table` answer:

```
library(data.table)

dt<-as.data.table(dat)

dt[, newcounter := unclass(as.factor(Phase)), by = Id]
```

---

**EDIT**

To account for the newly phrased question, here is a possibility using `data.table`.

```
dt <- as.data.table(dat[, -4])        # Create data.table
setkeyv(dt, c("Id", "year", "Week"))  # Create key for data.table

dt2 <- unique(dt)                     # Get only unique rows by key

dt3 <- dt2[, Weeks.observed := seq_len(.N), by = "Id"] # Create new variable

dt[dt3]                               # Merge data.tables back together
```

Comment: @EndreGrünerOfstad, please see the edit to my question - perhaps it can help.